# Constructing a multi-dimensional array in Julia

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

In MATLAB, the following syntax can be used to create 1-d matrix `a` and 2-d matrix `b`:

```
a = [2,3]
b = [2,3;4,5]
```

In Julia, constructing the 1-d array `a` using the same syntax works. However, constructing the 2-d array `b` using the same syntax fails.

Defining `b` as follows works:

```
b = cat(2,[2,4],[3,5])
```

Is there a syntactical shortcut for explicitly defining 2-d arrays in Julia? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also say [1 2; 3 4], which gives the same result as in Matlab.

Comment: the lack of commas is sad, but I guess we have to please both Euros and Americans, with their different comma and period conventions

Answer (score 6):

You're likely looking for this:

```
a = [2,3]
b = [2 3;4 5]
```

Here's the relevant paragraph from the "[Major Differences From MATLAB](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/getting-started/#major-differences-from-matlab)" section of the Julia docs:

> Concatenating scalars and arrays with the syntax `[x,y,z]` concatenates in the first dimension (“vertically”). For the second dimension (“horizontally”), use spaces as in `[x y z]`. To construct block matrices (concatenating in the first two dimensions), the syntax `[a b; c d]` is used to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax works (but is not as terse as the MATLAB equivalent):

```
b = [[2 3],[4 5]]
```

Comment: Does not work in julia 0.5 or 0.6. (It used to work in 0.3 when this answer was written). But it is now out of date.

Answer (score 0):

As of Julia 0.6
depending on which dimension you seek, you could use

```
# hcat
b = [[2, 3] [4, 5]]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}: [2 4; 3 5]

# vcat
c = [[2 3] ; [4 5]]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}: [2 3; 4 5]
```